# Objects are not valid as a React child when trying to map data from my api

Tags: reactjs, object, axios

I am getting the error

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {id, recipe_dificulty, recipe_id, recipe_name, recipe_steps})

I am using Axios to get my data here is the data that is being given to my react project.

https://pastebin.com/ydNrFLBW (Too much information to post here)

Here is my Mealplans class which is where the info is first used.

```
export default class Mealplans extends Component {   constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
          mealplanItems: []
      }   }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/all-mealplans'
    ).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      this.setState({
        mealplanItems: this.state.mealplanItems.concat(
          response.data["mealplans"])
      })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("ERROR!", error)
    })   }

  render() {
    const mealplanRecords = this.state.mealplanItems.map(mealplanItem => {
      return <MealplanItem mealplanItem={mealplanItem} />
    })
      return (
          <div>
            <div className="mealplan-page-header">
              <h1>Newest Mealplans</h1>
              <hr />
            </div>
              <div className="content-container">
                {mealplanRecords}
              </div> 
          </div>
      )   } }
```

Comment: What is your `MealplanItem`? Can you show us your code for that component?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the mealplanItem is `{object}`(`{id, recipe_dificulty, recipe_id, recipe_name, recipe_steps}`)   in the `MealplanItem` and it is printing it as it is.

React does not print the object.

in `MealplanItem`

```
//for example...

<div>
  <span>{mealplanItem.id}</span>
</div>
```

Try it like this.